# Redirect to / route in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, redirect

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app ...>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans ...>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <bean class="controllers.HomeController"></bean>
    <bean class="controllers.UserController"></bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />
</beans>
```

redirect.jsp simply redirects me to `home` route.

So, say I start a server and I get a url: `localhost:8080/my-project` and because resources are set up in applicationContext like so:

`<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />`

and all images/resources are set up using `resources/image/some-image.jpg` routes, the above URL doesn't load those resources (css/js/image/... files).

However, if I change the url to just `localhost:8080/my-project/` (adding a slash at the end) all resources are loaded normally.

My question is how can I change it so resources will be loaded either way (while still maintaining RESTful URL's), or how can I redirect, so when a user visits `localhost:8080/my-project` the server automatically redirects to `localhost:8080/my-project/`? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code it will work i have add static resources now instead of typing resources type static and check .. i am sure it will work .

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans ...>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <bean class="controllers.HomeController"></bean>
    <bean class="controllers.UserController"></bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/static/**"/>
</beans>
```

- Serving Static Resources

Comment: <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />     try to put "/resources/" only inside the location

Comment: okay forget about my code just try to put  location="/resources/" instead of location="/WEB-INF/resources/" inside your code.

Comment: yep, that's what I did as well, but that destroys everything (resources aren't being loaded whatever the url is).. edit: actually, in both cases the resources are not loaded (the only reason they loaded a moment ago was because it was still cached) edit2: also tried changing to location="resources/" just to see if relative paths work, but no.

Comment: Try to use like this `<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/static/**" />` and in your css/js/images files like `<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/script/login/login.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: For solving cached files problem normally I create one timestamp variable in a ServletContextListerner and use it in all static files `@Override
 public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
sce.getServletContext().setAttribute("cacheHash", new Date().getTime()); }` and `<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/script/login/login.js?${applicationScope['cacheHash']}" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: @user2669657 sorry, for the (very) late response, but yeah, I found that answer on another thread a few days ago. Regardless, accepting answer! :) (talking about the `${pageContext...}` solution)